# Qemu suddenly doesn't find any bus for the virtual mouse and keyboard: -device usb-tablet: No 'usb-bus' bus found for device 'usb-tablet'

Tags: kvm, qemu, libvirt

I've installed macOS Catalina some time ago in Qemu/KVM and it worked okay for a few months till today when I needed something and wanted to boot the virtual machine. This error pops up:

```
Error starting domain: internal error: qemu unexpectedly closed the monitor: 2022-01-11T10:16:53.873634Z qemu-system-x86_64: -device usb-tablet: No 'usb-bus' bus found for device 'usb-tablet'
```

I can see the `usb-tablet` but I don't know what its purpose it's, and since I'm not an expert in Qemu by any means, I thought about asking about it here, because I didn't find any info about this specific error at all.

##### EDIT

From what I was able to find out, I did find out that `qemu` actually complains about not finding a bus for the mouse and keyboard. I've removed the lines, first for the mouse. then for the keyboard and the VM boots with no issues just like before but of course, as you might have guessed, I don't have any keyboard and mouse to work within the VM.
[image: Mouse]
[image: Keyboard]

#### My question is how do I fix this? I've tried one method but it doesn't work.

##### I only get this error with the macOS VMs, my other 12 VMs are running just fine, Windows and Linux.

Here's the virtual machine's XML:

```xml
<domain xmlns:qemu="http://libvirt.org/schemas/domain/qemu/1.0" type="kvm">
  <name>HighSierra</name>
  <uuid>2bca0dd6-cec9-4717-9ab2-0b7b13d111c3</uuid>
  <title>HighSierra</title>
  <memory unit="KiB">4194304</memory>
  <currentMemory unit="KiB">4194304</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement="static">4</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type arch="x86_64" machine="pc-q35-4.2">hvm</type>
    <loader readonly="yes" type="pflash">/home/me/Hackintosh/HighSierra/OVMF_CODE.fd</loader>
    <nvram>/home/me/Hackintosh/HighSierra/OVMF_VARS-1024x768.fd</nvram>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode="custom" match="exact" check="none">
    <model fallback="forbid">qemu64</model>
  </cpu>
  <clock offset="utc">
    <timer name="rtc" tickpolicy="catchup"/>
    <timer name="pit" tickpolicy="delay"/>
    <timer name="hpet" present="no"/>
  </clock>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>restart</on_crash>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64</emulator>
    <disk type="file" device="disk">
      <driver name="qemu" type="qcow2" cache="writeback" io="threads"/>
      <source file="/home/me/Hackintosh/HighSierra/OpenCore/OpenCore.qcow2"/>
      <target dev="sda" bus="sata"/>
      <boot order="2"/>
      <address type="drive" controller="0" bus="0" target="0" unit="0"/>
    </disk>
    <disk type="file" device="disk">
      <driver name="qemu" type="qcow2" cache="writeback" io="threads"/>
      <source file="/home/me/Hackintosh/HighSierra/mac_hdd_HighSierra.img"/>
      <target dev="sdb" bus="sata"/>
      <boot order="1"/>
      <address type="drive" controller="0" bus="0" target="0" unit="1"/>
    </disk>
    <disk type="file" device="disk">
      <driver name="qemu" type="raw" cache="writeback"/>
      <source file="/home/me/Hackintosh/HighSierra/HighSierra.img"/>
      <target dev="sdc" bus="sata"/>
      <boot order="3"/>
      <address type="drive" controller="0" bus="0" target="0" unit="2"/>
    </disk>
    <controller type="sata" index="0">
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x1f" function="0x2"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="0" model="pcie-root"/>
    <controller type="pci" index="1" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="1" port="0x8"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x01" function="0x0" multifunction="on"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="2" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="2" port="0x9"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x01" function="0x1"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="3" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="3" port="0xa"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x01" function="0x2"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="4" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="4" port="0xb"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x01" function="0x3"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="5" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="5" port="0xc"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x01" function="0x4"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="6" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="6" port="0xd"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x01" function="0x5"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="7" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="7" port="0xe"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x01" function="0x6"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="8" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="8" port="0xf"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x01" function="0x7"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="9" model="pcie-to-pci-bridge">
      <model name="pcie-pci-bridge"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x01" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="virtio-serial" index="0">
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x02" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="usb" index="0" model="ich9-ehci1">
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x07" function="0x7"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="usb" index="0" model="ich9-uhci1">
      <master startport="0"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x07" function="0x0" multifunction="on"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="usb" index="0" model="ich9-uhci2">
      <master startport="2"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x07" function="0x1"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="usb" index="0" model="ich9-uhci3">
      <master startport="4"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x07" function="0x2"/>
    </controller>
    <interface type="bridge">
      <mac address="52:54:00:e6:85:40"/>
      <source bridge="virbr0"/>
      <model type="vmxnet3"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x09" slot="0x02" function="0x0"/>
    </interface>
    <serial type="pty">
      <target type="isa-serial" port="0">
        <model name="isa-serial"/>
      </target>
    </serial>
    <console type="pty">
      <target type="serial" port="0"/>
    </console>
    <channel type="unix">
      <target type="virtio" name="org.qemu.guest_agent.0"/>
      <address type="virtio-serial" controller="0" bus="0" port="1"/>
    </channel>
    <input type="mouse" bus="ps2"/>
    <input type="keyboard" bus="ps2"/>
    <graphics type="spice" autoport="yes">
      <listen type="address"/>
    </graphics>
    <audio id="1" type="spice"/>
    <video>
      <model type="vga" vram="65536" heads="1" primary="yes"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x09" slot="0x01" function="0x0"/>
    </video>
    <memballoon model="none"/>
  </devices>
  <qemu:commandline>
    <qemu:arg value="-device"/>
    <qemu:arg value="isa-applesmc,osk=ourhardworkbythesewordsguardedpleasedontsteal(c)AppleComputerInc"/>
    <qemu:arg value="-smbios"/>
    <qemu:arg value="type=2"/>
    <qemu:arg value="-device"/>
    <qemu:arg value="usb-tablet"/>
    <qemu:arg value="-device"/>
    <qemu:arg value="usb-kbd"/>
    <qemu:arg value="-cpu"/>
    <qemu:arg value="Penryn,kvm=on,vendor=GenuineIntel,+invtsc,vmware-cpuid-freq=on,+ssse3,+sse4.2,+popcnt,+avx,+aes,+xsave,+xsaveopt,check"/>
  </qemu:commandline>
</domain>
```

I also have, on another device, two virtual machines: Catalina and HighSierra. and I get the exact same error there.

Comment: I do not know about gui, but for cli try `qemu-system-x86_64 -accel kvm -name debian -vga virtio -usb -device usb-tablet -display gtk,gl=on -cpu host -smp 1 -m 2048 -drive format=qcow2,file=ubuntu.qcow2 -daemonize`. Here, replace ubuntu.qcow2 with the qcow2 image of macOS. The positional parameter you are missing is `-usb`.

Comment: Thanks, indeed that was the option I was missing. Now it's all working good again. I thought about looking through the `OpenCore-BOOT.sh` and compare with what I have in `virt-manger` and yes, this was the only thing related to that. Easy

Comment: Doesn't work booting the VM, that way. It has 3 drives attached. Check out the project on GitHub and see what's all about: https://github.com/kholia/OSX-KVM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I've found the real fix for this myself while searching.**

First of all, I think I have to mention that this the project that I'm using: [OSX-KVM from Kholia](https://github.com/kholia/OSX-KVM).

While looking to fix the issue, I was looking through the original `OpenCore-Boot.sh` file which I used to boot the machine in the first place and there was this `-usb` option here.

```xml
-usb -device usb-kbd -device usb-tablet
^   ^
```

Option that I was somehow missing right now in `virt-manager` file, I don't know how this happened cause I never played around those lines.

#### FIX

So I've only had to add that in the `qemu args` section, like this:

```xml
    <qemu:arg value="-usb"/>
    <qemu:arg value="-device"/>
    <qemu:arg value="usb-tablet"/>
    <qemu:arg value="-device"/>
    <qemu:arg value="usb-kbd"/>
```

Enjoy!